# Python: How can I make this work?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I make this work?

```
number = int(raw_input("Number: "))
if number != !!!!!!!!NUMBER TYPE IS NOT AN INT TYPEEE!!!!!!!!!
    print "NO!"
else
    print "YES!"
```

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    num = int(raw_input("Number: "))
    print("Yes!")
except ValueError:
    print("No!")
```

Comment: @EduardoMorales: really? It works for me (tested in Python 2.7 and 3.4  ** by replacing `raw_input` with `input`)

Answer (score 0):

```
number = raw_input("Number: ")

if not number.isdigit():
    print "NO!"
else:
    print "YES!"
```

Comment: `int("-1234") == -1234` but `"-1234".isdigit() == False`

Comment: Point taken. Try would as you created the only solution.